# Any USB-C only switch in existence?

Tags: usb, switch, usb-c, display-port

I am searching for a USB-C switch with **only** USB type C ports.

Ideally:

- 4 USB-C ports for peripherals/devices/...
- 2-4 USB-C for PC's (so 2 (or better 4) PC's should be switchable)

---

As a use-case that would be primarily multiple displays connected via USB (DisplayPort Alternate Mode; displays daisy-chained; at least 2x 1440p), USB peripheral devices.

Comment: Can you clarify what kind of devices you want to plug into this hub/switch? There's a big difference between the USB-C connector and the USB protocol. USB-C can carry USB 2.0, 3.2 Gen1 (3.0), or 3.2 Gen2. A switch or splitter that works with 3.2 Gen2 would be extremely expensive to make so they're quite hard to find; But if you only need USB 3.0 (3.2 Gen1) then you might simply be able to use a USB-A device with dongles to convert its ports to USB-C. If you're trying to have video over USB-C then that will need a very special device too, not just any USB-C "switch".

Comment: Ideally probably USB4 as it supports PCIe and DisplayPort.
However the main criteria would be video (multiple displays via daisy chaining) and peripheral USB devices.

Comment: I think chx's answer is the way to go if you actually have USB 4.0 on the host PCs. Thunderbolt 4 and 4.0 are apparently interchangeable now, but older versions of either of those are not (even though they all use USB-C).

Answer (score 1):

https://sabrent.com/products/sb-tb4k

Two devices upstream

Three USB4 ports downstream

It won't get any better any time soon.

Comment: This is a thunderbolt switch, which seems like it's probably a good choice if TB works for OP. Does it work for USB 4.0 hosts too though? Definitely doesn't work for USB 3.2?

Comment: There's no such thing as USB 4.0. You are thinking of USB4 and it obviously works with it: TB4 is a certification program for certain USB4 devices and it so happens every USB4 host fits this certification even if Intel doesn't want to work with AMD/ASMedia to give it to them. (The only exception is the artificial monitor limit on the base Apple Mac chips.)

Answer (score 0):

This [USB-C switch from Aten](https://www.aten.com/us/en/products/usb-&-thunderbolt/peripheral-switches/us3342/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIr92nsvmY9gIVmrp3Ch1aeQ_jEAAYASAAEgKcgvD_BwE) goes already into the right direction *but does not fulfil all my requirements*:

- Only **one** USB-C input
- 2 PCs can be connected (still holds min. requirement but far from perfect)

However a plus is that it provides a port for an external power supply and a port for remote control.

[image: Rear view - USB-C ports for power and source PCs]